# How can I construct a stochastic model from a deterministic one (dealing with population dynamics)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-pde

I found a deterministic [model](http://files.umwblogs.org/blogs.dir/8053/files/2013/04/KellyBrownHonors.pdf) using differential equations on the population decline of honey bees. Is there a way to convert the model to a stochastic model by introducing a random variable somewhere?